# Having a hidden class on a table row causes colspan to not work in the print window

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, hidden

Here is a fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/m5et9fwL/

Basically what the problem is is that when having a hidden class on a `tr` or `td` which should be hidden on the normal page but visible when printing, the colspan decides to stop working, as demonstrated by the fiddle. I've tried adding colspan directly to the CSS but this does not solve the issue either unfortunately.

Does anyone know what could be the cause for this and how would I go about solving this?

Markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>1123124i12049120491</td>
        <td>1123124i12049120491</td>
        <td>1123124i12049120491</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden" colspan="4">1130192301312312314124819248912849128491289481294812948192849128498129481294892849184294814</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="print">print page</button>
```

Print activation:

```
$('.print').on('click', function() {
    window.print(); 
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

@media print {

    .hidden {
      display: block;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `td` must have a `table-cell` display, not a `block` one.
Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/m5et9fwL/1/

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

@media print {

    .hidden {
      display: table-cell;  
    }
}
```

Or, if the `.hidden` class is on a `tr`, the display property has to be `table-row`.

Comment: Why of course... Makes so much sense now, appreciate it mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@media print {    
.hidden {
  display: table-row;        
}}
```